# <picture> <source> relative to width of <picture>

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am trying to put a responsive image on website. i have the following code

```
<picture>
<source media="(max-width: 400px)" srcset="cache/images/image.w400.jpg"></source>
<source media="(max-width: 800px)" srcset="cache/images/image.w800.jpg"></source>
<source media="(max-width: 1000px)" srcset="cache/images/image.w1000.jpg"></source>
<source media="(max-width: 1200px)" srcset="cache/images/image.w1200.jpg"></source>
<source media="(max-width: 1920px)" srcset="cache/images/image.w1920.jpg"></source>
<img src="/imgresizer/images/image.jpg">
</picture>
```

The size of the  picture element will be determined by the containing div.

The size of the containing div will be random. it can be directly in the .container, it can also be in .col-sm-6

Problem is here is the max-width relative to the viewport.
I want the source to be selected based on the width of the picture element. Is this possible? if so, how?

PS. I prefere a solution without javascript.

EDIT: What i am missing is a way to have the  select a  based on his own width. I guess this is not in hte HTML5 standard?

Comment: You need javascript for this, because i assume you are also doing this for performances and CSS solution would load all images, then only display the one corresponding to your screen.

Comment: What IS the width of the picture element? Is there a ballpark ratio between the viewport and the picture, or is this totally dynamic?

Comment: The ratio will be totaly dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img class="image-responsive" data-srcset="cache/images/image.w400.jpg 400w, cache/images/image.w800.jpg 800w, cache/images/image.w1000.jpg 1000w, cache/images/image.w1200.jpg 1200w, cache/images/image.w1920.jpg 1920w" data-src="images/image.jpg" sizes="720px" src="images/image.jpg">

window.onload = function() {
        var images = document.getElementsByClassName('image-responsive');
        for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            var width = images[i].parentElement.offsetWidth;
            images[i].setAttribute('sizes', width+'px');
            images[i].setAttribute('src', images[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
            images[i].setAttribute('srcset', images[i].getAttribute('data-srcset'));
        }
    };
```

For now i made an image with srcset and a little javascript.

This replaces the sizes attibute with the width of its parent. Where the default sizes = 400px.

This uses javascript :(.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the max-width queries to use percentages instead? That way as your picture element resizes it will pick different sources based on the same percentage width of the picture.

Comment: I dont realy understand what you mean. could you elaborate?

Comment: You say you want your image to be relative to the picture element instead of the viewport, but you have not said how you are setting the size of the picture element. Is it relative to the viewport, or to a containing element?

Comment: The size of the picture element will be determined by the containg div

Comment: OK, and what determines the size of the containing div? Can you post a bit more code?

Comment: The size of the containing div will be random. it can be directly in the .container, it can also be in .col-sm-6